# Firing from Starkiller Base

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, physics

In the movie we see

> Starkiller Base fire upon and destroy five planets (or a mixture of 5 planets and moons) within a single solar-system.

This event appears to be observed simultaneously and instantaneously/in real-time by multiple characters from a variety of very different vantage points.  For instance:

1. Han, Rey, Finn, et al. from the surface of whatever world they're on (which as I understood it was still some distance away from Republic space).
2. Leia and the other Republic commanders observe from their command center.
3. The troops who fire the weapon appear able to observe its results.

My question is, what is the relative position of all of these vantage points that would allow simultaneous observation like that?  Even from a vantage point within the targeted system it would likely take minutes, at least, to observe the full effects of the weapon.

Was everyone actually in more-or-less the same place (or at least, equidistant from the target zone) when the weapon was fired?  Meaning the First Order was firing on a *very* nearby target (which would invite the question of why the Republic would allow such a massive and obvious superweapon to be constructed so close to their area of influence?)?

Or is this just a case of the movie not taking practical physics into account?

Comment: Talk about a vaguely-titled duplicate.  But yes, duplicate nonetheless.

Comment: people... go a bit overboard on despoilering things lately.